# How do I show BAT (or BEE) availability calendar on front-end?

Tags: bookings

I previously built a site in D7 which showed the availability of two apartments for rent, using the [availability_calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) module . The client easily selected dates and marked them available, booked or unavailable, and the result showed in 3 months of full-calendar on the front-end.

I have now rebuilt the website in Drupal 8, but I fiund that the availability_calendar module has not been ported, and there is no real alternative.

As suggested by the availability_calendar developers, I have tried to rebuild the entire availability system using [BAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/bat), which proves extremely complicated (and overkill for what I need). I have also tried [BEE](https://www.drupal.org/project/bee), which leads to the same main problems I find in BAT.

- Both BAT and BEE provide a back-end, but I can't figure out how to display the availability on the front end. I tried Views and PHP code from the back-end, but I get either an empty full-calendar or a title and blank space or error messages.
- Both BAT and BEE seem to focus on things being bookable at the front-end.  All I want is a simple system where clients can mark the two apartments as available/booked/unavailable. No need for visitors to be able to book online. I only need the client-set availability displayed in a calendar. How do I switch the displayed availability to read-only?
- All bookings my client takes run from 12 noon of the first day to 12 noon on the last day. However, neither BAT nor BEE seems to be able to give me half day display? Switching from daily availability to hourly does change the way the calendar in back end looks, but I still can't get half days booked. For example, if I have a first booking ending 12 noon on Saturday, and a second one starting from 12 noon that day, I get two full Saturdays displayed, with the second booking underneath the first. Ideally I'd like triangles on first and last day, so bookings nicely fill up the calendar and don't separate onto a new line.

Comment: Uh, this is a rather broad issue. I think you are better off asking that in the mentioned module's issue queue as support request.

Comment: @leymannx - I felt it was not so much a bug or issue with BAT or BEE, but my lack of ability, hence a call for help here rather than at the module(s)?